# How can i implement "snooze" in iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification, alarm

I want to develop an alarm app and implement like "snooze" feature.

First, user set the time using datePicker. ann when user ignores the notification,

it pushes notification again after 5 mins.

So i used UILocalNotification and set repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit

then i can receive the notification every day but i don't know how to implement "snooze"

only when user ignores the first notification.

Answer (score 7):

You can schedule up to 64 local notifications.

So schedule them with your 5 minute interval.

If the user ignores the notification (does not open your app), the next notification will go off in 5 minutes.

If he actually open your app, you can get the scheduled notification via

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

and cancel all of them via

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification];
```

Then you reschedule for the next alarm with the 5 minute interval.

Comment: you mean i schdule the notification twice? if so, i don't know how to reschedule the next alarm with 5 minute interval in next day, when user open my app and i cancel all of the old notifications.

Comment: This approach is awesome!

Comment: Are you sure about that 128 local notifications? According to Apple's documentation, _the system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications and discards the rest_.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I corrected my answer.